# How to store values

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I construct one, different values for each id ,this is my code

```
$errorMessage = array();
   $result = CheckpointErrormsg::where('checklist_template_id', $checklist_template_id)
             ->orderby('error_message', 'asc')
             ->select('checkpoint_id', 'error_message')
             ->get()->toArray();

   foreach ($result as $row) {
        $errorMessage[$row['checkpoint_id']][] = $row['error_message'];
   }
   return $errorMessage;    
}
```

This is my blade view page:

```
 {!! Form::select($checkpoint['id'].'_c[]', isset($error_messages[$checkpoint['id']])?$error_messages[$checkpoint['id']] : array(), $explode_values, array('multiple'=>'true', 'class'=>'form-control js-example-tags select2','id'=>$checkpoint['id'].'_c')) !!}
```

in my database inserted this formate :values 0,1,2 but I need red,blue,green
please help me

Comment: what is output on `print_r($errorMessage);`?

Comment: This is my output

Comment: array (size=2)
  '6e8a7bfc9b664ef3ad9812b7605e2304' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1111' (length=4)
      1 => string '2222' (length=4)
      2 => string '3333' (length=4)
  'b551b723eb864a318c0a4a8fc3da6ba6' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'blue' (length=4)
      1 => string 'green' (length=5)
      2 => string 'red' (length=3)
      3 => string 'yellow' (length=6)

Comment: return array values